# Qt Creator + Profiler (Windows)

Tags: windows, qt, creator

Всем привет!

Вопрос такой

Нужен профайлер под Qt Creator - узнать, какие функции надо оптимизировать - это будет полезно для проекта

Работаю под Windows 7 x64.

Собственно, вопрос простой - какие профайлеры, знакомые Вам, подходят под оп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер!

Если используется компилятор mingw, то в нем есть встроенный профайлер (gprof).
В файл проекта нужно добавить:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -g3 -pg
QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG += -pg -lgmon
```